# Set custom path for npm module for node project

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I have an Angular project and for some reason, I wanted some of the npm library that I installed through `npm install` is installed under a custom path.

Example:

> npm install a

This will be located to where it is expected

```
|-- node_modules
    |-- a
```

But let say I want the other library located to a custom folder

> npm install b

This will be located to where it is expected

```
|-- node_modules
    |-- customFolder
       |-- b
```

Is this possible? Should I change something on `package.lock.json`?